# projects for carousel with materialize on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, carousel, materialize, owl-carousel-2

anyone knows projects for carousel or carousel slides for materialize on rails?.

I mean different to embed carousel on materialize.

or know a tuto to implement owlcarousel on rails ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/acrogenesis/owlcarousel-rails

Answer (score 1):

OWN implementation is super simple:

1. Put [this](https://github.com/acrogenesis/owlcarousel-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets) to your /vendor/ directory (each file should be placed in relevant folder, e.g. css => stylesheets, js => javascript)
2. Add

   //= require owl.carousel

and

```
@import 'owl.carousel'
```

.. [may be other files]

to you application.js and application.scss (css)

3. You may need to precompile additional assets by

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( owl.min.css owl.min.js )

4. Restart rails server.
5. Now js (coffeeScript)

   $('.carousel').owlCarousel
   navigation: true
   items: 1
   loop: true
   nav: false
   autoplay: true
   autoplayTimeout: 5000
   autoplayHoverPause: true
   return
6. Layout (this is slim template).

   .carousel.owl-carousel.owl-theme
       .item
         .ui.container
           .slogan 
             span Slide 1 
       .item
         .ui.container
           .slogan 
             span Slide 2 
       .item
         .ui.container
           .slogan 
             span Slide 3